# Inserting a row at a specific location in a 2d array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array in numpy where I want to insert a new row. Following question [Numpy - add row to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881453/numpy-add-row-to-array) can help. We can use `numpy.vstack`, but it stacks at the start or at the end. Can anyone please help in this regard.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`numpy.insert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((2, 2))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
# In the following line 1 is the index before which to insert, 0 is the axis.
>>> np.insert(a, 1, np.array((1, 1)), 0)  
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> np.insert(a, 1, np.array((1, 1)), 1)
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```