# How do I concatenate an array into a 3D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

In my Python application I have a 3D matrix (array) such this:

```
array([[[ 1., 2., 3.]], [[ 4.,  5.,  6.]], [[ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])
```

and I would like to add, in a particular "line", for example, in the middle, zero arrays. At the end I would like to end with the following matrix:

`array([[[ 1., 2., 3.]],
    [[ 4.,  5.,  6.]],
    [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
    [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
    [[ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])`

Anybody knows how to solve this issue? I tried to use "numpy.concatenate", but it allow me only to add more "lines".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of

[Inserting a row at a specific location in a 2d array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298797/inserting-a-row-at-a-specific-location-in-a-2d-array-in-numpy)

For example:

```
a = array([[[ 1., 2., 3.]], [[ 4.,  5.,  6.]], [[ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])
output = np.insert(a, 2, np.array([0,0,0]), 0)
```

output:

```
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.]],
       [[ 4.,  5.,  6.]],
       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
       [[ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])
```

**Why this works on 3D array?**

See doc [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert).
It says:

```
numpy.insert(arr, obj, values, axis=None)
...
Parameters :
    values : array_like
        Values to insert into arr.
        If the type of values is different from that of arr,
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        values is converted to the type of arr. values should be shaped so that
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        arr[...,obj,...] = values is legal.
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
```

So it's very wise function!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
result = np.r_[ a[:2], np.zeros(1,2,3), a[2][None] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
>>> a = np.array([[[ 1., 2., 3.]], [[ 4.,  5.,  6.]], [[ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])

>>> np.concatenate((a[:2], np.tile(np.zeros_like(a[0]), (2,1,1)), a[2:]))
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.]],

       [[ 4.,  5.,  6.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])
```

The 2 in `(2,1,1)` given to `tile()` is how many zero "rows" to insert.  The 2 in the slice indexes is of course where to insert.

If you're going to insert a large amount of zeros, it may be more efficient to just create a big array of zeros first and then copy in the parts you need from the original array.