# How append a column to an existing matrix in Python

Tags: python

Total beginner on Python here, and all I want to do is add a column of 1s to a matrix, and I cannot seem to accomplish it. I wanted the new column to be the first one of the matrix. What I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((4, 4))

for i in range(len(a)):
  a[i] = [1] + a[i]
```

But apparently that just adds 1 to every element in my matrix. I am using Python3

Comment: This question might be duplicated but the answer is `np.hstack((np.ones((len(a), 1)), a))`

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-an-numpy-array :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I had seen the question you linked but I had not seen the answer containing the code you just posted. I had seen another answer and wasn't able to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((4, 4))
b = np.ones((len(a), 1), dtype=float)
print np.hstack([b,a])
```

[You can brush your skills by following this tutorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/data-manipulation-visualisation-r-python/tutorial-data-manipulation-numpy-pandas-python/tutorial/?utm_campaign=&utm_medium=email&utm_source=miscellaneous)