# Concatenate two numpy arrays along first axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have one array with dimension `(1538,4)` called `X_scaled` and another array with dimensions `(1538,1)` called `Y_mlp`. I want to add `Y_mlp` to `X_scaled` such that `Y_mlp` becomes the fifth column in `X_scaled`. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an extra column to an numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-an-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy-hstack).

> ```
> numpy.hstack(tup)
> ```
>
> Take a sequence of arrays and stack them horizontally to make a single
>   array.

```
import numpy as np

X_scaled, Y_mlp = ..., ...

Y_mlp = Y_mlp.reshape(-1, 1)   
out = np.hstack((X_scaled, Y_mlp))

print(out.shape)
```

Output:

```
(5, 5)
```

Concatenation occurs along the second dimension.

Comment: It says dimensions don't match when I concatenate. When I enter Y_mlp.shape it prints(1538,)

Comment: @Alex_ban That means that your arrays don't have that shape... You need to do `Y_mlp = Y_mlp.reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: What does (1538,) means? There is no 1 after the comma as it should be.

Comment: @Alex_ban Please understand. You need 2 arrays with 2 dimensions each for concatenation to work. `(xxx, )` means that it is a 1D array. `(xxx, 1)` means it is a 2D array with xxx rows and 1 column. Look at my edit. Follow those steps, and if it works, then all's well.

Comment: With 2d arrays, concatenation occurs on the 2nd dimension (axis=1).  `hstack` doesn't add much to `concatenate(..., axis=1)`.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah, sorry. My terminology was off.