# how to add a column into the numpy matrix?

Tags: numpy

here is my code to add additional column into *x_vals*, but i keep getting this error:

```
x_vals = np.array([x[0:4] for x in iris.data])
np.concatenate([x_vals, np.array([x[0] for x in iris.data])],1)
```

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

can anyone help me ?

Comment: In place of `x[0]` try either `x[0:1]` or `x[0, None]`.

Comment: Did you check the shape of `x_vals` and of the thing you are trying to add to it?  The first thing we do when we get `dimensions` errors is to check the shapes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an extra column to a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: I like this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18207544/7919597