# Creating an array by adding to shape of existing array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I have a numpy array:

```
X = np.array([[1,0,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [0,1,0],
              [1,0,1]])
```

which has a shape of `(4,3)`

I would like to change this shape into `(4,4)` by adding 1 to the second dimension of the array, via:

```
X_b = np.ones((X.shape+(0,1)))
```

but what I get is:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,3) into shape (4,2,0,1)
```

What is the right way to do it?

Basically I want `X_b` to have a shape of `(4,4)` if `X.shape = (4,3)`

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code, do this instead:

```
X_b = np.ones(X.shape + np.array((0,1)))
```

The catch here is that `X.shape` returns a plain Python `tuple`. By adding `(0,1)` you were actually performing tuple concatenation, instead of pairwise addition like you intended.

Of course, you could also just stick an extra column on to your existing array with `append`:

```
X_b = np.append(X, [[1]]*X.shape[0], axis=1)
```

Comment: `X_b[:,:-1] = X` and then use `X_b` as input... probably doing the same thing. your answer looks good. Just waiting the minutes

Comment: @oakca assuming `X_b` was created with `np.ones`, then yep. The one "gotcha" is that `X_b` will be of dtype `float64`, which is the default for `np.ones`. Thus the `dtype`s of `X` and `X_b` may not match (eg if `X.dtype==int`)

Comment: Or `np.hstack((X, np.ones((4,1), dtype=np.int)))`, which I find easier to visualize.

Comment: @xnx There's a [whole bunch of these array-growing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8486294/425458), and they're all roughly equivalent. Ideally you use none of them and instead just preallocate all your arrays (whose size you magically know in advance). Internally, both [`append`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L4476-L4528) and [`hstack`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ccfbcc1cd9a4035a467f2e982a565ab27de25b6b/numpy/core/shape_base.py#L236-L288) are thin (5-10 lines) wrappers around `concatenate`.

Comment: Here you can find more about the thema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-a-numpy-array

Comment: `X.shape+np.array(0,1)` `*** TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: @oakca I fixed the answer. Just had to add some parentheses (and remove some unneeded ones).

Comment: still the same error. and sorry about that maybe old version let me check