# How can I add a column to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I add a column containing only "1" to the beginning of a second numpy array.

```
X = np.array([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])
```

I want to have X become

```
[[1,1,2], [1,3,4],[1,5,6]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an extra column to a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use the [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)

  ```
  new_x = np.insert(x, 0, 1, axis=1)
  ```
- You can use the [`np.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) method to add your array at the right of a column of `1` values

  ```
  x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
  ones = np.array([[1]] * len(x))
  new_x = np.append(ones, x, axis=1)
  ```

Both will give you the expected result

```
[[1 1 2]
 [1 3 4]
 [1 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> X
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

>>> np.insert(X, 0, 1, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a new array is going to be created in any event, it is just sometimes easier to do so from the beginning.  Since you want a column of 1's at the beginning, then you can use builtin functions and the input arrays existing structure and dtype.

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)               # input array
z = np.ones((a.shape[0], 3), dtype=a.dtype) # use the row shape and your desired columns
z[:, 1:] = a                                # place the old array into the new array
z
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy.insert() will do the trick.

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
np.insert(X,0,[1,2,3],axis=1)
```

The Output will be:

```
array([[1, 1, 2],
   [2, 3, 4],
   [3, 5, 6]])
```

Note that the second argument is the index before which you want to insert. And the axis = 1 indicates that you want to insert as a column without flattening the array.

For reference:
[numpy.insert()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)