# Does Python support declaring a matrix column-wise?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

In *Python numpy* when declaring matrices I use *np.array([[row 1], [row 2], . . . [row n]])* form. This is declaring a matrix row-wise. Is their any facility in *Python* to declare a matrix column-wise? I would expect something like - *np.array([[col 1], [col 2], . . . [col n]], parameter = 'column-wise')* so that a matrix with n columns is produced.

I know such a thing can be achieved via transposing. But is there a way for *np.array([...], parameter = '...')* being considered as a row or column based on the *parameter* value I provide?

****np.array()* is just used as a dummy here. Any function with above desired facility will do.

Comment: create the data using `pandas`, column-wise, then do a `to_numpy()` to get numpy array! Or use [`column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) method.

Comment: This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8489498/14739759) may be of use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [65]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
Out[65]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

There's a whole family of `concatenate` functions, that help you join arrays in various ways.

`stack` with default axis behaves much like `np.array`:

```
In [66]: np.stack([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], axis=0)
Out[66]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

`np.vstack` also does this.

But to make columns:

```
In [67]: np.stack([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], axis=1)
Out[67]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

`np.column_stack([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` does the same.

transposing is also an option: `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).T`.

All these '*stack' functions end up using `np.concatenate`, so it's worth your time to learn to use it directly.  You may need to add dimensions to the inputs.

[66] does (under the covers):

```
In [72]: np.concatenate((np.array([1,2,3])[:,None], np.array([4,5,6])[:,None]),axis=1)
Out[72]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time of array-creation itself, you could use `numpy.transpose()` instead of `numpy.array()`, because `numpy.tranpose()` takes any "array-like" object as input:

```
my_array = np.transpose ([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print (my_array)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
```