# Add a single element to all elements of an array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

points=[[-1,0],[5,6]]
points = np.array(points)

points_new=np.array([])

for point in points:
    point=np.append(point, 0)
    points_new = np.append(points_new, point)

print(points_new)
```

I am trying to add 0 to end of elements. Desired output will be

```
[[-1.  0.  0.]  [5.  6.  0.]]
```

but I get

```
[-1.  0.  0.  5.  6.  0.]
```

from the code above. Can you tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an extra column to a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: **Read** the docs: If `axis` is not specified, `values` can be any shape and will be flattened before use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the solution you're looking for, but if it suits your code you can append the list first before making it an array:

```
import numpy as np

points=[[-1,0],[5,6]]

for point in points:
    point.append(0)

points = np.array(points)
print(points)
```

This prints:

```
[[-1  0  0]
 [ 5  6  0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to requirement of list in np.append instead of np.array i think

In the backend it will call concatenate so you can try below snippets

We can concatenate compatible numpy arrays, numpy arrays become compatible when their shape size is same.

That is why they single shape points.shape[0] is made into 2D by broadcasting over new dimension using np.newaxis.

Also you dont need new axis if you already define shape appropriately in np.zeroes

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points=[[-1,0],[5,6]]
>>> points = np.array(points)
>>> np.concatenate([points, np.zeros(points.shape[0])[:,np.newaxis]], axis=1)
array([[-1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  0.]])
>>> np.concatenate([points, np.zeros((points.shape[0], 1))], axis=1)
array([[-1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  0.]])
>>> print('trying to generalize')
>>> np.concatenate([points, np.zeros((points.shape[0], *[1] * len(points.shape[1:])))], axis=1)
array([[-1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `np.append()` :
here's how it works:

```
>>>np.append([1, 2, 3], [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
array([1, 2, 3, ..., 7, 8, 9])
```

Try using usual python lists and do your logic, after that change `points_new` to `np.array`

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2D array and just want new column with zeros on right side you might do

```
import numpy as np

points=[[-1,0],[5,6]]
points = np.array(points)

points_new=np.hstack([points,np.zeros((points.shape[0],1))])
print(points_new)
```

output

```
[[-1.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  6.  0.]]
```

Explanation: I create 2D array of appriopiate shape using `np.zeros` then stacked it horizontally (hstack) with existing array.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate a column of zeros to all the rows as below:

```
points=[[-1,0],[5,6]]
points = np.array(points)

rows = points.shape[0]
zeros = np.zeros(rows)
points_new = np.c_[points, zeros]

print(points_new)
array([[-1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 5.,  6.,  0.]])
```