# combining array and list elemint by index

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array (which comes from a kdtree):

```
array =  [[a b c d e]
          [a b c d e]
          [a b c d e]]
```

and a list :

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to do some list comprehension (using `array` and `lst`) that makes it look like this:

```
desired_result = [[a, b, c, d, e, 1]
                  [a, b, c, d, e, 2]
                  [a, b, c, d, e, 3]]
```

I am familiar with list comprehension just not familiar enough to know how to deal with this.

Comment: Can you share the data type of the `array`?

Comment: yeah they are all numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list comprehension:

```
result = [l+[x] for l,x in zip(array, lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to list comprehension if `array` is of the type `numpy.ndarray`:

```
result = numpy.c_[array, lst]
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505658/7789963) for more details.