# Append Error Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
#Each element of the FeatureFolds and ClassesFolds is a matrex by itself
#the classes are 5000x1 each
#the features are 5000 by 800 each


def FindAllVectors(c):


testC= c
FeatureFolds = [f1, f2 ,f3 ,f4 ,f5 ,f6 ,f7 ,f8 ,f9 ,f10]
ClassesFolds = [f1c ,f2c ,f3c ,f4c ,f5c ,f6c ,f7c ,f8c ,f9c ,f10c]
arr = np.array([])
for x in range(0,10):
    for y in range(0,5000):
        if (ClassesFolds[x][y][0]== testC):
            if (arr == []):
                arr = np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y]) 
            else:

                arr = np.append((arr, np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y])))

d= arr.shape
return d
```

returns an error:
TypeError: append() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
Could anyone explain why?

And append does not add it as a new row?How could I fix that?

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear, you've passed a single arg, it looks like you have extraneous parentheses: `arr = np.append((arr, np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y])))` should be `arr = np.append(arr, np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y]))`

Comment: Perhaps earlier you did `import numpy as np`, and maybe `numpy`'s `append()` takes two arguments, so the single argument `(arr,  np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y]))` is insufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Your `append` line is passing a single param of a tuple rather than 2 arrays:

```
arr = np.append((arr, np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y])))
               #^- extraneous (  another one here -^
```

should be

```
arr = np.append(arr, np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y]))
```

Comment: Use `vstack`:  `arr = np.vstack([arr, np.array(FeatureFolds[x][y])])` see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881453/numpy-add-row-to-array

Comment: What can I replace for append so that the FeatureFolds[x][y] is added as a new row?

Comment: Vstack throws back : ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactl
PS:Have to wait 5 min to accept it

Comment: Please post another question then, as that is a different issue to this one, also you should post data that reproduces your problem