# Trying to append arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this piece of code:

```
csvData = np.array([]);
csvData = np.append(csvData, ['1', '2016-01-01', 'Some text'])
csvData = np.append(csvData, ['2', '2016-01-02', 'Some more text'])
print(csvData)
```

it outputs: `['1' '2016-01-01' 'Some text' '2' '2016-01-02' 'Some more text']`

I would like to get something like:
`[['1' '2016-01-01' 'Some text'], ['2' '2016-01-02' 'Some more text']]`

I tried wrapping my data string into `[]`. The reason I am doing this, because I want to collect each csv row, sort it by specific column and iterate data rows.

Any other solution is welcome.

I would sort using something like: `csvData [np.argsort(csvData [:,2])]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3881504/1749888

Comment: Learn to use `np.conacatenate` before trying to use `np.append` as though it were a list append clone.  You need to understand array dimensions when using `numpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired output is a list of list which can be generated by the below code:

```
csvData = []
csvData.append(['1', '2016-01-01', 'Some text'])
csvData.append(['2', '2016-01-02', 'Some more text'])
#csvData would be
#[['1', '2016-01-01', 'Some text'], ['2', '2016-01-02', 'Some more text']]
```

But since you use numpy library, for converting it to the appropriate type this line helps:

```
csvData = np.asarray(csvData)
#csvData would be
[['1' '2016-01-01' 'Some text']
 ['2' '2016-01-02' 'Some more text']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save `np.append` in subarray and then append it to main array. Something like that:

```
array = []
subarray = ['1', '2016-01-01', 'Some text']
...
array.append(subarray)
```

Don't know what object `np` is.

Comment: `np` is the `numpy` package - numerical arrays; see the tag

Answer (score 1):

Before I give the solution please take look at [why you should not build not repeatedly append to numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569063).

Having said that if you must do it (it *very very* inefficient and highly discouraged) here is how it *can be done*

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> r1 = ['1', '2016-01-01', 'Some text']
>>> r2 = ['2', '2016-01-02', 'Some more text']
>>> ar = np.empty(shape=(0,3))
>>> ar = np.vstack( [ar, r1] )
>>> ar = np.vstack( [ar, r2] )
>>> ar
array([['1', '2016-01-01', 'Some text'],
       ['2', '2016-01-02', 'Some more text']], 
      dtype='<U32')
```

**note:** [pands](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library built over numpy may be more suitable for your needs. It provides function to read CSV files [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)